# One Vert.x instance, many deployVerticle calls, same event loop?

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle, abstractverticle

If I have one Vertx instance and I deploy many Verticles on it, calling method .deployVerticle() many times, the would run all on the same event loop or in different ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will be deployed across all available event loops with a round-robin algorithm. So if you have four event loop threads, and eight Verticles to deploy, you'll end up with two verticles per event loop thread.